# How to add a leading zero based on range of values in postgres within an integer column

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

New to postgres and unsure how to accomplish the following. I have a table as follows:

```
create table if not exists my_table (
   id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY primary key,
   key              int default 0
)
```

What I am trying to do is take an integer value (`my_key`) and if it's `>= 0 and < 10` then add a leading zero (0) to it and insert it into `my_table.key`

I have tried to_char(my_key::integer,'09')::integer where `my_key = 0` and it doesn't insert `00` within the `key` column.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Integers don't store leading zeros because `00001` is exactly the same value as `1`. You should format that number when you _display_ the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading zeros don't change the value of an integer, so this is a question about formatting numbers.

If you want to display the `id` column with leading zeros, you could do that like this:

```
SELECT to_char(id, '00'), key
FROM "table";
```

The format `00` formats the number as a two-digit string with leasing zeros. If `id` is greater than 99, the number cannot be formatted like this, and you will get `##`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) for details about `to_char` and the available formats.